# Mojang API - Get Security Cuestions

Tags: c#, api, post, get

Estoy intentando saber si una cuenta tiene preguntas de seguridad o no, (cuenta de minecraft).

Ya hice el sistema que inicia secion y consigue el auth token como lo indica en la pagina de la api (https://wiki.vg/Mojang_API) y mi problema es que al hacerle un request get a la api para conseguir las preguntas de seguridad (https://api.mojang.com/user/security/challenges).

La api me da la siguiente respuesta:

```
`{"error":"Unauthorized","errorMessage":"The request requires user authentication"}`
```

Por lo que vi en la pagina de la api (https://wiki.vg/Mojang_API) hay que poner un header con el token (El token se consigue haciendo un post a la api principal con la informacion de la cuenta usuario:contraseña y si es valida te dará el token, luego se captura con un parse y se pone en el header) que es lo que estoy haciendo, pero no se porque sigue saliendo la misma respuesta,

```
`{"error":"Unauthorized","errorMessage":"The request requires user authentication"}`
```

Supongo que será porque estoy poniendo mal el header a lo mejor? Este es mi codigo.

```
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"; 
    req.KeepAlive = true;
    req.IgnoreProtocolErrors = true;
    req.ConnectTimeout = 5000;
    req.Cookies = null;
    req.UseCookies = false;
    string content = "{\"agent\":{\"name\":\"Minecraft\",\"version\":1},\"username\":\"" + array[0] + "\",\"password\":\"" + array[1] + "\",\"requestUser\":true}"; //AQUÍ PON EL CONTEN (EL DEVICE DE LA API)
    req.AddHeader("User-Agent:", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");
    req.AddHeader("Pragma:", "no-cache");
    req.AddHeader("Accept:", "*/*");
    string str1 = req.Post("https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate", content, "application/json").ToString();
                            
    string Nick = Parse(str1, "availableProfiles\":[{\"name\":\"", "\",\"");
    string TK = Parse(str1, "accessToken\":\"", "\"\"");
    Request.hits++;
    req.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + TK);
    string str2 = req.Get("https://api.mojang.com/user/security/challenges", null).ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(str2);
```

Basicamente siempre me sale el mismo error al intentar hacer un request.get a la api de mojang para conseguir las preguntas de seguridad de la cuenta :( como si el auth token no estaria bien puesto en los headers o no estaria bien capturado.

Comment: ¿Has leído la documentación? ¿Conoces lo que es un Token de autenticación?

Comment: Si, el Token se consigue haciendo un post a la siguiente api: https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate igual que lo hago en el codigo, al hacer el post con el usuario y contraseña, si es correcto te dará un token temporal en el responce, o que hago es capturarlo pero no se porque aun asi cuando lo pongo en header sale como si no estubiera bien puesto

Comment: Utiliza postman o cURL y manda la petición con el valor que tienes en TK, me late que hay algo que está mal construido.

Comment: Por cierto, lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822